# Tile the floor with tiles with given size

Tags: algorithm

We are given `n` tiles, each one is a square of given size. Now, we are given `m` different sizes of the floor. Floor is a rectangle of size `a x b`. We would like to now how many types of tiles we can use to tile given floor. We can tile given floor when the floor will be tiled totally and without any tile poking.

So the obvious thing here is that tile of size `d x d` could tile the floor of size `a x b` if `gcd(a, b) mod d = 0`. So the simplest way would be:

1. go over all sizes of floors
2. for each size of floor:

   a. calculate gcd(a, b)

   b. go over all tiles and check how many of them divides by gcd(a,b)

But this seems to be too slow - I got 2/3 tests passed on the task. The complexity seems to be `O(m*n*log(size))`.

Any idea how to do that better (faster)?

Comment: Please post a link to the contest question page, so that potential answerers can verify that the contest is not currently active.

Comment: The ranges of all input variables, and a sketch of your code would help make this a better question. At the moment, it's not clear exactly what your code does, but you're asking for something faster.